# Angular firebase get many variable

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to pull all the uids childs from the database under the request list, but it only writes the last one. Is there any way to commemorate them all?

[image]

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.cs.getItems().subscribe(items => {
      console.log(items);
      items.forEach(values => {
          console.log(values.key);
          let key = values.key;
          console.log("serdar "+key);
          this.cs.getSubItems(key).subscribe(subItems => {
             this.listRequest= subItems;
              subItems.forEach(uid => {
                  console.log(uid.payload.val());

              });

          });
      });
  });
```

}

Comment: You are getting only the subitems of the last item in `listRequest`. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, but i want to take subitems of all item. not only last item.

Comment: `this.listRequest= subItems` will cause the value to be overwritten in each `getSubItems()` method. Instead push the new items to the array so that previous items preserves.

Comment: i add array but it gave same result:(                                                            https://i.imgyukle.com/2019/12/17/RtXLyP.png                                        https://i.imgyukle.com/2019/12/17/RtXKOo.png

Comment: I think he meant replacing `this.listRequest` with a push to an array of listRequests. If the issue persists, could you try that?